# Probability with loaded and fair dice

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory, dice

I own five different six-sided dice. Four of the dice are fair dice, meaning they have values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. However, one of the dice is loaded; thus, it never shows 1, 2 or 3, but is equally likely to show the values 4, 5, or 6. *For my experiment, I will pick up one random dice and roll it twice.*

The first thing I would like to calculate is the probability of getting two sixes. To calculate this, I first calculated the probability of getting one six and multiplied it by two. Suppose $S$ = *event that two sixes are rolled.*
$$P(S) = 2(\frac45(\frac16) + \frac15(\frac13)) = .4 $$
However, I am not sure if this is correct. I need to calculate this because I would also like to calculate $P(L|S)$ where L = *event that a loaded die was picked.* Additionally, I feel this is incorrect, because if I change the '2' to a '10' to calculate it for 10 rolls instead of 2, I get a value over 1 which makes no sense. To summarize, how can I calculate $P(S)$ properly so I can calculate $P(L|S)$?

Comment: Probability that "two sixes are rolled" is NOT at all equal to 2 * probability of "six is rolled the first time". With your approach you will get that probability of "100 sixes in 100 experiments" is much more that 1, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\frac16$ and $\frac13$ should be squared at first, not doubled at the end. The correct calculation for $P(S)$ is
$$P(S)=\frac45\cdot\frac1{6^2}+\frac15\cdot\frac1{3^2}=\frac1{45}+\frac1{45}=\frac2{45}$$
The second term above is $P(L\cap S)$, so
$$P(L\mid S)=\frac{P(L\cap S)}{P(S)}=\frac{1/45}{2/45}=\frac12$$